# Android's RotateAnimation and a multi-state button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an ImageButton, and the 'src' drawable for it is a state-dependent selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_camera_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_camera_default"/>
</selector>
```

and put into use like so:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_width="72sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_camera_capture"/>
```

In order to have it oriented the right way up as the device physically turns, I rotate this button using an animation:

```
    RotateAnimation newAnim = new RotateAnimation(oldOrientation, newOrientation, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    newAnim.setRepeatCount(0);
    newAnim.setDuration(1000);
    newAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    newAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
```

This works fine on the Samsung Galaxy S4. The button performs a rotation animation, stays in the new rotation afterwards, and pressing it at any time changes the image as per the state selector, but retains the appropriate orientation, thanks to the `setFill...` calls.

On the Samsung Ace 3, it also works fine for the most part, but pressing the button causes the pressed image to immediately show in the default orientation, i.e. no rotation, and once no longer pressed, the non-pressed image remains in that incorrect orientation.

How can I resolve this?

Of course, I guess I could take ownership of the button state changes in-code and handle this whole thing myself, but I'm wondering what my expectation should be in the first place, and whether I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this myself by doing as I suggested might be necessary, and handling the pressed state drawable change myself, rather than using the XML selector.

```
/*We transition the button between drawables based on state.
* This should be done via a selector in XML, but that doesn't play nicely
* with the rotation animation on all phones.
*/
captureButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
    /**{@inheritDoc}*/
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED
                captureButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_camera_pressed);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // RELEASED
                captureButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_camera_default);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

This seems to work on both devices without the need for any further changes. Perhaps there's a bug in the Android version on the Ace 3.